# Window Function Lag on Calculated Column

Tags: lag

I need to take forward a calculated value ...

FOR EX:

```
FLD1   FLD2  FLD3
a       100   10
a             20
a             30
```

I need an out put in this fashion

```
FLD1   FLD2  FLD3   diff
a       100   10    90 (fld2-fld3)
a             20    70(diff of prev row  -fld3)
a             30    40 (diff of prev row -fld3)
```

I'm not able to do a lag on diff because its a calculated column

Thanks in adv

Comment: I think you are going to need a column to order the `FLD3` values.

Comment: I'm not worried of fld3 values ..My whole idea is how many values does fld2 can eat up...

Comment: You need a means to _order_ the `FLD3` columns so that you can compute a rolling difference.